# How do I force an INSERT into a table with a unique key if it's already in the table?

Tags: mysql, insert-update, upsert

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (studentId TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
```

I want to insert records into the table, if I insert a student twice I want 
the second insert to override(update) the first record.

```
INSERT INTO Students (StudentId, name) VALUES ('123', 'Jones');
INSERT INTO Students (StudentId, name) VALUES ('123', 'Jonas');
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: You ... ["UPSERT"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert) -- UPdate or inSERT. Compare MySQL's `REPLACE` with `INSERT ... OR UPDATE` (they are subtly different!)

Comment: Only why do you have StudentId type TEXT? why not integer? bigint?

Answer (score 17):

Try [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

```
REPLACE INTO Students (StudentId, name) VALUES ('123', 'Jonas');
```

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Comment: So why not `INSERT ... OR UPDATE`? (There are differences :)

Comment: `REPLACE` is the correct answer to the question. It forces an insert (or rather an entire replace) if the row already exists. `OR UPDATE` requires you to specify the fields and values to update - which is a different solution to a different question.

Comment: what happens it the row does not exist? Will `REPLACE` do a normal `INSERT` then?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Yes, if the row does not exist `REPLACE` do as `INSERT`

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the **[`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)** syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Students
    (StudentId, name) 
  VALUES ('123', 'Jones')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  name = VALUES(name) ;
```

See this answer: [insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update) for differences between `REPLACE`, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and `INSERT IGNORE`.

---

But please, tell us that the **`studentId TEXT PRIMARY KEY`** is a typo. Do you really have a Primary Key that is [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html) datatype? The name (`studentId`) suggests that it could be a simple `INT` or `INT AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: The studentId may have alpha's in it, this looks what I want - great thanks!

Comment: Even in that case, a `VARCHAR(n)`, where n=10 or 20 (the maximum length) would be much better that `TEXT`.

Comment: @ypercube Student ID numbers are generally best suited as text (of some sort, likely varchar as noted). They can contain leading, trailing 0s, be multiple widths, and may be in forms such as '903.12345' with a floating decimal location, etc (I have seen "all of the above"). Whether this should be a surrogate key is another debate entirely ;-) +1 for `INSERT ... ON` and a link to differences with `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using MySql - just use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) instead of INSERT

Comment: So why not `INSERT ... OR UPDATE`? (There are differences :)

Comment: You can INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

any many more, but why do you need it, if you have great and simple solution with REPLACE.

Comment: @pomaxa: `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` do almost the same thing. The first first deletes the record, then adds a new one, the second updates the existing record.

Comment: The difference has to be taken into account if you have foreign keys (especially if they are cascading on delete).

Comment: But in this case, you can't be sure, that the user is the same; But you are right, you need to be aware about cascad delete on foreign keys...

Comment: Foreign keys can also prevent the Delete (and thus the Replace). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: I don't know when I do the 2nd INSERT if the record exists or not, what happens if I use REPLACE and the record doesn't exist? Will it get INSERTed?

Comment: @stevemcl: yes, `REPLACE` will insert if the record doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with a table that already had data in it, and no foreign keys, so my solution was very simple:
I added a new column called `temp_id` and made that a primary key, then afterwards deleted the old ID column, and then renamed the `temp_id` column to `id`.